# Bash check is file with variable name inside loop exists

Tags: bash, loops, conditional-statements

I would like to check if a file exists. Of course this is explained in many places. Now I am inside a loop like:

```
for ((l=0;l<5;l+=1));

do

if -a FILENAMEl #FILENAME contains l!!!!!!!!!

then "FILENAMEl exists"

else

do

.............

fi

done
```

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? What is `-a` there? Are you trying to construct a filename with a suffix and check for that (so `file1`, `file2`, etc.)?

Comment: Do you want to check for a file named **exactly** by the number, or containing the number as a substring?

Comment: Also, the "substring" approach may not work as you want. "file102" contains "2", after all. Do you want "file102" to return true for "2", in addition to "102"?

Comment: A better question would give examples (if not a specification) of your filenames.

Comment: (also, `-a` is not a bash command; it's a possible argument to the `test` command, which can also be written as `[`, but it does nothing in and of itself).

Comment: Really sorry. I should explain better, but am having troubles. Next try:

Comment: With the bash script I am working on I would like to start processes, which will write files. The server regularly kills some of my processes from the loop, and as I do not want to run all processes again, I would like to check, if the program wrote the file and only start the process, if the file was not written previously. So: if the file existists (and the filename contains the variable that is run through in the loop!), then echo "file exists", if not, start the process.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're trying to find which files exist in the filename format file1.csv, file2.csv, etc...

```
 for i in {1..5}; 
      do f="file$i.csv"; 
         if test -e $f; 
            then echo "$f exists"; 
            else echo "$f does not exist"; 
         fi 
      done
```

Perhaps what you need is simply a `find`

```
 find . -name "file?.csv" -size +10k
```

You can restrict the file name to suffix 1..5 and do an action on the find result (check for find's -exec or more generally xargs as below).

```
find . -name "file[1-5].csv" -size +10c | xargs head -1
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! It works! One more question: How do I insert the additional condition that the file (it is a .txt) has entries or is larger than 10kB?

Comment: If it's a text file, easiest will be using `size = $(wc -c < filename)`

Comment: I found $f -ge 9, where f is the filename and 9 is 9kB. So here I check if the file is greater or equal to 9kB. But I am not sure about the syntax if I want to check for both conditions (file exists and is greater than...) if [[ -e $f ]] && [[$f -ge 9]] ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are mixing the syntax of a variable name `l` with that of a file name.  If you wish to use them together, to form part of a filename with a variable, you need a syntax break (caused by `"$"`), or use braces (`{}`).

If the file name has a variable in the middle, then braces work best.  For example:  `"my_file_${l}_head.txt"` would create files like `my_file_1_head.txt`, `my_file_2_head.txt`, etc.

Here is your original example corrected:

```
for ((l=0;l<5;l+=1))
do
    if test -a FILENAME$l 
    then echo "FILENAME$l exists"
    else echo "FILENAME$l doesn't exist"
    fi
done
```

However, I wouldn't write code this way.

I only took your example and changed it as little as possible to show you the essential difference.

Here's another way to write it, using a more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) approach:

```
for l in {1..5}; do
  file="filename$l"
  if [[ -a "$file" ]]; then
    echo "$file exists"
  else
    echo "$file does not exist"
  fi
done
```

If you want more minimalism, here's yet another approach:

```
for l in {1..5}; do f="filename$l"
  [[ -a "$f" ]] && echo "$f exists" || echo "$f does not exist"
done
```

Now, if you need to do something other than just print out the status, using function calls to make the extra work modular works well:

```
for l in {1..5} ; do f="$filename$l"
  [[ -a "$f" ] && process_file $f || non_existant_file $f
done
```

Then, elsewhere, you should define both `process_file` and `non_existant_file`:

```
process_file() {
   local file="$1"
   # do whatever is needed for an existing file
}

non_existant_file() {
   local file="$1"
   # do whatever is needed for a non-existant file
}
```